# PDF end of file detection

Tags: pdf, merge, eof

We are developing a software for PDF merging, We are facing an issue that how to detect the end of text in the PDF file so that we can crop that PDF file and merge the second PDF from the point where the first PDF ended (content wise). We are able to detect end by page wise but how to detect end of file content wise ? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In essence you will have to analyze the existing content streams of the last page, determine where stuff is drawn, build a surrounding rectangle, and compare that with the media or crop box of the page. Furthermore you probably want to try remove footer lines first, but recognizing them can be difficult. Ah yes, you might also want to consider annotations; you probably don't want added stuff to overlap e.g. Form fields.